# Figuring out MySQL data information on an ec2 instance

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-ec2

I installed MySQL on an EC2 instance and need to get some information about that database so I can setup pligg on it.

The info it needs are:  Database Name, Username, Password, Database Server and Table Prefix.  Is there a simple way to retrieve this information?  I assume I need to use PuTTy but I couldn't find specific info on it.

Thanks

Comment: what OS have you got installed on your ec2 instance?

Comment: I think you have to login to mysql, and create a database and user to be used for your  pligg application.

Answer (score 0):

The database server is most likely to be localhost and the rest are values that you must set. The docs for whatever application you are installing should give a tutorial on how to create these.

You might find [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) useful if the application provides a SQL script to run and you don't want to use the command line.